# Why the running time is N^2?

Tags: runtime

```
    for (int i = 0; i*i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j*j < N*N*N; j++)
            sum++;
```

It is one of the exercises in the course Algorithms, Part I, on Coursera.

The outer for loop is the square root of N, and the inner loop is somehow the square root of N (j*j) and also N^3 (N * N * N). How does that become N^2?

Comment: THe goal of the exercise is for you to use math to determine why it is running longer. YOu could prove the runtime by reducing the equation and showing that way that it is quadratic equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to answering this question. First, let's discuss how to determine the running time of programs will multiple loops. What we care about is how many times the sum++ statement is called - that's what we are measuring. Consider this program:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        sum++;
```

First we look at the outer loop, and we see that it will be run N times. Now, we look at the inner loop, and we want to know how many times it will be run *for each iteration of the outer loop*. Once we know that, we can simply multiply the two values and will obtain the total number of times the sum++ has been called. In this case, it is easy to see that each time the outer loop is run, the inner loop will be run N times. Since the outer loop is also run N times, this has a running time of N^2.

As you noted, the outer loop will indeed be run sqrt(N) times. Now, we have to see how many times the inner loop will run for each iteration of the outer loop. We can do this by simplifying the counter in each loop. By doing this, we can see that the inner loop will be run N^(3/2) times each time the outer loop is called.

Why is this true? Well, observe that what you wrote is equivalent to

```
for (int i = 0; i < N^(1/2); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < (N*N*N)^(1/2); j++)
        sum++;
```

Since for each iteration of the outer loop we run the inner loop N^(3/2) times, we can simply multiply these to get a total running time of O(N^2).

Comment: Thanks, make sure to accept the answer if it was useful to you.